# Table name like SQL syntax in Spring boot

Tags: spring, spring-boot, hibernate, spring-mvc, spring-data-jpa

I can't create table order because table name match sql syntax. How can I resolve it? Is there any property in `application.properties` support it?

```
@Data
@NoArgsConstructor
@AllArgsConstructor
@Entity
@Table(name = "order")
public class Order {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Integer id;

    @Column(nullable = false)
    private Double productPrice;

    @Column(nullable = false)
    private Double shipPrice;

    @Column(nullable = false)
    private Integer status;
    
}
```

Comment: It is not recommended to use reserved words, you can use something like 'orders'. It will save you from so many unwanted errors in future.

Answer (score 1):

Use

```
@Table(name="\"order\"")
```